# Detecting OS version and using the right PhantomJS binary

Tags: node.js, phantomjs, node-webkit

I'm currently trying to use PhantomJS inside Node.js & Nwjs using OS X. However, I'm wondering if I deploy the app to Windows users, will they be able to run the app as well?

Is there a way to detect what OS the user has and use the right binary for it?

Comment: Generally you need to package the correct binary for the OS. That's why you always see people offering different download links for OSX, Windows and Linux. The exception is if you don't want to distribute the binaries - then use npm and tell the user to run npm install (or use bower, either way the user will need to install node.js separately)

Comment: Have you tried https://www.npmjs.com/package/phantomjs?

Comment: @slebetman I didn't think of this obvious answer, guess my brain is fried at this point haha. You're totally right, I can do different versions. Thanks man, much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this functionality is built in node.js.

Here's how it's done in one of the nw.js sample apps, mp3 encoder (which obviously need different binaries on different OS to work): https://github.com/zcbenz/nw-sample-apps/blob/master/mp3-encoder/lib/main.js#L29

In short:

```
 var platform = require("os").platform;
 var pathToBin;

 switch (platform()) {
    case "darwin":
      pathToBin = "vendor/bin/osx/phantomjs";
      break;
    case "win32":
      pathToBin = "vendor/bin/win32/phantomjs.exe";
  }
```